# Why do freight charges over $1,000.00 roll back to $1.00 on my site?

Tags: shipping

I am having an issue with my site where if my freight costs go above 1000.00, the cost for shipping returns $1.00. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Like it just rolls over? That's really bizarre. I haven't heard of that happening.

Comment: If my Freight shipping total goes above $999.99, the recalculate total goes to $1.00. Any ideas? I am stumped.

Comment: No idea, but I'm curious to know if anybody else has seen this issue before.

Comment: Did you try to define it as 10k? Sounds like a numbering format issue maybe. I had an issue last week: german format (1.000,00€), replaced , with . -> 1.000.00 and then the first . was interpreted as decimal separator and therefore as 1.00. Maybe magento does something like this somewhere. I think shipping > 1k was never tested? :)